# Facebook URL sharing issue with Social framework - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-share, social-framework

I am getting issue for Facebook sharing (with social framework) on when i am appending my URL.

Its giving error on Facebook page.
[image: Sharing issue on facebook page]

Code which i am using for sharing content on facebook:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
     ])
{
    SLComposeViewController *fbSheetOBJ = [SLComposeViewController
                                              composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              ];
    [fbSheetOBJ setInitialText:@""];
    [fbSheetOBJ addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[dict_BusinessDetails valueForKey:@"shared_lnks"] valueForKey:@"facebook_link"]]];
    [fbSheetOBJ addURL:[NSURL 
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[dict_BusinessDetails valueForKey:@"business_logo"]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    [fbSheetOBJ addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    [self presentViewController:fbSheetOBJ animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

> Issue with only iOS devices, Everything is working fine with simulator.

Answer (score 0):

insted of

```
fbSheetOBJ.addImage(UIImage.imageWithData(imageData))
```

try using:

```
bSheetOBJ.addImage(UIImage.pin_decodedImageWithData(imageData))
```